# Has anyone experienced zRotation greater than 2 Pi?

Tags: sprite-kit, rotation, swift3

I'm getting values for zRotation less/greater than -/+pi with Swift3 (e.g. 7.41137313842773, in radians at about 0,5Pi).  It happens when rotating a node using the approach described below.

Code is

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        newLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        turnAngle = atan2(newLocation.y - lastLocation.y - mySprite.position.y, newLocation.x - lastLocation.x - mySprite.position.x)
        mySprite.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: turnAngle, duration: 0.1))
        lastLocation = newLocation
        print("mySprite zRotation: \(mySprite.zRotation)")
    }
}
```

I also notice a jittery jump in the sprite at the point when the sprite is rotated to pi/2 (absolute).  If this is normal behaviour, is there a way to recalculate zRotation between -/+Pi or 0-2Pi?

Comment: I don't think this is recommended, since this action run will be called a lot and you will be stacking movement actions, which might have unexpected results. Better just set the zRotation "manually". `touchesMoved` being frequently called will make the rotation smooth.
By recalculate, you mean a function to convert an angle to a equivalent between -/+Pi or 0-2Pi?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in your code there are two point to analyze:
`SKAction` and `zRotation`.

---

The first (`SKAction`) should be considered in general (not about this issue). If you want to launch an `SKAction` like 'rotate' inside a cycle, because it have a duration you should check if this action is finished before to launch another. An example:

```
extension SKNode
{
    func actionForKeyIsRunning(key: String) -> Bool {
        return self.action(forKey: key) != nil ? true : false
    }
}

if !self.mySprite.actionForKeyIsRunning(key: "rotation") {
    self.mySprite.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: turnAngle, duration: 0.1),withKey:"rotation")
}
```

---

Speaking about `zRotation` and your issue the reason you have a wrong `zRotation` value is because you are using an action. zRotation is a node property: properties of nodes undergoing animation are not updated at each step in the simulation. You can set `zRotation` to rotate your node:

```
self.mySprite.zRotation = turnAngle
```

or create a physics body and set the angular velocity.

For more details about `SKAction` and node properties look the [official Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH11-SW13) where there is this note:

> **When You Shouldn’t Use Actions**
>
> Although actions are efficient, there is a cost to creating and
>   executing them. If you are making changes to a node’s properties in
>   every frame of animation and those changes need to be recomputed in
>   each frame, you are better off making the changes to the node directly
>   and not using actions to do so. For more information on where you
>   might do this in your game, see [Advanced Scene Processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW1).

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for all your great feedback. I've changed the approach to use update() for each frame and touchesEnded() to make sure the final result is 'cleaned up' and do changes within the scene. I think zRotation values (even if I'm overloading the processing capacity) that are bigger than +/- pic shouldn't happen, no matter what is done. That said, I couldn't find a documented limit from Apple. I work around the problem by calculating the modulus and dividing by 2pi. This doubles the number of conditions (0-2pi negative and positive) but works ok. I'll do some more research though.

Comment: Why shouldn't it happen?  4 PI is a valid angle, it means 2 rotations,  there is a valid reason to use this value

Answer (score 1):

As @PietroPepe has pointed out,  you are stacking actions one on top of the other.  Let's break down your code:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
```

This tells us that your touch calls will be done multiple times throughout the life cycle of your touch.  Even with a quick touch down and up action,  it is very possible to go through at least 2 calls on this method.

```
    newLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    turnAngle = atan2(newLocation.y - lastLocation.y - mySprite.position.y, newLocation.x - lastLocation.x - mySprite.position.x)
```

The point of this code is to have the sprite move at the change of the touch from last position to current position

```
    mySprite.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: turnAngle, duration: 0.1))
    lastLocation = newLocation
    print("mySprite zRotation: \(mySprite.zRotation)")
}
```

}

Finally this point of the code says do it in 1/10th of a second.

Now let's run through a scenario.  We touch the screen, move it, and let go.

The amount of time it took to perform it was 4 frames,  this means 1 touchBegan, 2 touchMoved, and 1 touchEnded.

in our toucheMoved events, we calculate a change of 60degrees, each time.

Now a frame is 1/60th of a second keep in mind.

Our rotation event will take 1/10th of a second to go from 0 to 60, so 6/60th seconds, 6 frames.

This means every frame we are moving 10 degrees.

Now we come to the second frame of the rotateBy.

The same logic as the first frame above will apply, so we will now have another series of rotations that will be moving by 10 degrees.

This mean we now have 2 events rotating our sprite at 6 degrees each.

So the timeline is as followed:

Frames: 0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
         +10 +10 +10 +10 +10 +10
             +10 +10 +10 +10 +10 +10

Notice the inconsistent behaviors between the end and the beginning of your rotation?  This is why things look all screwy.

Now,  I am not sure of the desired effect you are looking for, but if I were to be doing this, I would be setting `zRotation` instead of using actions.

If you are looking for a delayed effect,  then use the `withKey` parameter on the `run` function so that you only have 1 action running, and use `SKAction.rotateTo` to have the sprite always rotating to the last possible touch location. This of course means you need to keep track of when touch first began, not when last touched.

This also gets a little tricky depending on desired effect, because you may need to keep track of the time that has elapsed between the number of `touchesMoved` events called and apply the time difference to your duration, so basically `duration:.01 - timeSinceTouchBegan`,